# Trouble installing jupyterlab with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-lab

I'm fairly new to interacting with Mac OS through command line but i'm trying to make more of an effort to understand the interaction with it especially when it comes to installing programmes for programming languages. I'm trying to install jupyterlab so i ran

```
>>> pip install jupyterlab
```

and something runs so i'm assuming it has been installed somewhere.

However when then run

```
>>> jupyter lab or >>>jupyterlab
```

I get for both (command not found)

```
-bash: jupyterlab: command not found
```

Now online i've seen regarding the installation it says 
"f installing using pip install --user, you must add the user-level bin directory to your PATH environment variable in order to launch jupyter lab."

Now this initially didn't mean too much to me but i've been looking into \bin files when looking at which version of python and i know

```
>>> which python
```

gives me the location of the binary for python. Naturally i tried

```
>>> which jupyterlab 
>>> which jupyter lab
```

but both give me nothing.

I also get this message when i type pip install jupyterlab

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not 
writeable
Requirement already satisfied: jupyterlab in 
./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (0.33.12)
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Firstly do i need to add the user level bin directory to my path environment variable? If so how do i find it and how do i do that? I would really appreciate any advice broken into steps for a complete beginner. I really want to understand this so i can try to prevent issues like this in the future. I should highlight i don't have conda installed and i would like to solve this problem with pip. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try to uninstall jupyterlab because it is installed using Python 2.7

```
pip uninstall jupyterlab
```

Then check that jupyter is non-existing by using:

```
which jupyterlab
```

And finally reinstall it using pip3 install instead of pip.
For pip to use python3.

```
pip3 install jupyterlab
```

Let me know if it worked ;)